# Retrieve customer full data from Dynamics ax 2012 and show it in MVCproject

Tags: c#, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aif

I want to list all customer information in grid-view using MVC c#. also i want to return data from c# to client as json format because I'm using angularjs.
I already create AIF and link it with my MVC project , but still i do not know how to retrive all customer data.

any help please

Comment: Do you have any sample code to start with?

Comment: its simple code , just get customer name and id and save it in object variable

Comment: Do you have access to the AX db? If you do, you can just query the the db from your MVC project and map the results to a model class then send it to frontend in any format you like(eg. json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

### Query Service [AX 2012]

The query service is one of the Microsoft Dynamics AX system services that enables you to issue a query for data without using an Application Integration Framework (AIF) document service or creating a custom service. The query service returns data in a dataset and implements a paging mechanism so that you can manage large amounts of data returned by a query.

[Walkthrough: Calling the Query Service with a Static Query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg863932.aspx)

Another option is to create a custom service or [add a service operation to a standard customer service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa607052.aspx)

Comment: in C# side, I know how to use dynamics ax. but in dynamics classes i do not know how to write a method that return all customer list (name, accountNum,....)

Comment: Then use the first approach (query service). This method doesn't require coding on Dynamics AX side. First link contains C# code that retrieve all customers from AX